# nHibernate persist IList<DayOfWeek>

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to persist an `IList<DayOfWeek>` using nHibernate?

```
public class Vendor
{
    public virtual IList<DayOfWeek> OrderDays { get; private set; }
}
```

If not, what are some common solutions; creating a class for OrderDays?, using an `IList<string>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible...

```
<bag name="OrderDays">
  <key column="VendorId" />
  <element type="System.DayOfWeek" />
</bag>
```

`VendorId` would be the FK column to `Vendor` in the `OrderDays` table (you can customize all of that)

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else is looking, the fluent version is as follows: HasMany(x => x.OrderDays).Element("DayOfWeek")